# Scanner.nextLine() no actúa correctamente después de Scanner.nextInt()

Tags: java, string, scanner

Tengo este código:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
int i2    = scan.nextInt();
    
System.out.println("natural= " + i2);
System.out.println("cadena = " + s2);
    
scan.close();
```

Que funciona correctamente:

> Esto es una cadena
> 1714
> natural= 1714
> cadena = Esto es una cadena

Pero si cambio de orden las líneas del `Scanner`:

```java
int i2    = scan.nextInt();
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

Ignora la línea `scan.nextLine()` y me da el resultado justo después de introducir el `int`.

> 1714
> natural= 1714
> cadena =

¿Alguien sabe que está pasando y cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: No has puesto ninguna cadena de entrada, no? @.@

Comment: @MiquelColl no es que no se la ponga, es que no me deja ya que ignora el `nextLine` puedes probarlo tu mismo :)

Comment: Tienes razón, y ya sé el por qué =P. Ahora te pongo la respuesta.

Comment: @MiquelColl grande! he editado la pregunta para clarificar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

El comportamiento del [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) no es el que esperas. Cuándo le introduces de entrada un `1714` en realidad estás introduciendo un `1714` y un *salto de línea*(`\n`) y el `nextInt()` no te consume el salto de línea (`\n`).

Eso significa que el `nextLine()` está leyendo este salto de línea (que es vacío --> `\n`).

Para solucionarlo, cuándo hagas un `nextInt()` pon siempre un `nextLine()` que no tendrá contenido.

A partir de tu código:

```
int i2    = scan.nextInt();
String saltoDeLinea = scan.nextLine();
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

Otra manera de solucionarlo es leer siempre con `nextLine()` y hacer un `cast` a posteriori:

```
int i2 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
```

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/1468942) del SO original dan algún detalle más, por si te interesa.

Comment: que bueno, no lo sabia! lo que puedes hacer `scan.nextLine();` directamente sin asignarlo a un `String` para ahorrar recursos (y el molesto warning) `:)`

Comment: @joc He editado `1` por `1714` ya que no importa el tamaño del int (y me gusta más el `1714`) `=P`

Comment: yo tambien he editado la pregunta para que coincida todo `:P`

Answer (score 0):

Al usar el nextDouble(), tiene el mismo comportamiento de nextInt();

hay que usar en la siguiente línea un lector de String
para capturar el salto de línea poder capturar el texto que necesitamos.

```
Double d = scan.nextDouble();
String saltoDeLinea = scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Hola Luis, gracias por tu contribución, por un lado estas contestando una pregunta que tiene seis años de formulada, por el otro, tu respuesta está en el límite entre respuesta y comentario, yo en tu lugar la eliminaría, para evitar recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una forma automatica de Scanner que en cada lectura por teclado te establece un patron delimitador. Por ejemplo el /n

Entonces quedaria:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimeter("\n");
String s2 = scan.next();
int i2    = scan.nextInt();
String s3 = scan.next();
```