# Problema clase Scanner en Java al introducir varios Strings como variables

Tags: java, string, java-util-scanner, scanner

estoy haciendo un programilla para clase algo más complejo que este, pero el principal problema que tengo es que necesito añadir mínimo dos nombres pero cuando ejecuto se salta que introduzca el primer nombre. Mejor me explico en código, esto es un pequeño ejemplo de lo que querría hacer:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Empleados {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Introduce un número");
            int z = e.nextInt();

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
            String nombre1 = e.nextLine();

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
            String nombre2 = e.nextLine();

            System.out.println();


            System.out.println(z + ", " + nombre1 + ", " + nombre2);


        }
    }
```

No sé si será un fallo en el código, soy bastante novato programando. En consola sale el siguiente resultado:

> Introduce un número
>
> 3656
>
> Introduce nombre
>
> //como veis, aquí no me deja entrar un nombre por lo que el resultado
>   de abajo sale vacío.
>                Introduce nombre
>
> Pedro
>
> 3656, , Pedro

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Acabo de encontrar este duplicado: [Scanner.nextLine() no actua correctamente despues de Scanner.nextInt()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint)

Answer (score 6):

### Tu problema es que el método [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) no consume el salto de línea

El método `nextInt` de [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) consume todo los números que encuentre, y nada más. Eso quiere decir que el *salto de línea* que pulsas al introducir tu número, y que en el buffer del `Scanner` se guarda como `\n`, no se consume:

```
3245\n // Scanner solo consume 3245, \n se queda
```

Cuando introduces el nombre *la primera vez*, en realidad tienes esto:

```
\nPedro\n
```

Y con `nextLine`, `Scanner` consume hasta el siguiente salto de línea, o `\n`. Es decir, tu Scanner está leyendo hasta el **primer** `\n`, y no hay nada.

### Solución

La solución clásica es limpiar el `Scanner` haciendo [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) después de cada `nextInt`:

```
System.out.println("Introduce un número");
int z = e.nextInt();
e.nextLine();
```

De esa manera se consumirá el primer salto de línea y el nombre no tendrá salto de línea antes.

Comment: Me gusta cómo lo explicastes. Lo siento que los votos hasta ahora en esta pregunta están un poco raros y agresivos. Siendo que este es un problema tan común, espero que al final quede claro que esta es la forma correcta de resolver este problema.

Comment: @sstan Muchas gracias =), después de publicar mi respuesta he leído la tuya y también me ha gustado mucho, por eso te dejé un +1.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es simplemente que `nextInt()` no consume el caracter de salto de línea cuando lee el número. De modo que la próxima vez que ejecutas `nextLine()`, allí enseguida consume el caracter de salto de línea que quedó en el buffer interno del `Scanner` de cuando entrastes el número.

Las mejores soluciones para este problema son las propuestas en la respuesta aceptada de esta pregunta en SO: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/4955425). Escoge la que prefieras:

1. Agregas un `nextLine()` justo después del `nextInt()`, simplemente con el propósito de consumir el caracter de salto de línea que quedó en el buffer:

   ```
   System.out.println("Introduce un número");
   int z = e.nextInt();
   e.nextLine(); // agrega esto
   ```
2. O, en vez de usar `nextInt()`, puedes usar `nextLine()` y luego convertir a un `int` usando `Integer.parseInt(s)`:

   ```
   System.out.println("Introduce un número");
   int z = Integer.parseInt(e.nextLine());
   ```

---

**¿Por qué no es buena idea usar las otras soluciones propuestas de cambiar los `nextLine()` a `next()`?**

Porque `next()` para de consumir la cadena cuando se topa con un espacio. De modo que si entras un nombre que incluye un espacio, vas a volver a tener el mismo problema de que te va a saltar un nombre, pero esta vez el segundo.

Por ejemplo, si cambias todos los `nextLine` a `next()`, y ahora tratas de entrar `Juan Carlos` como el primer nombre, verás que no te pedirá el segundo nombre, porque va a tomar `Juan` como el primer nombre, y `Carlos` como el segundo.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar `next()` en lugar de `nextLine()` ya que

> - [**next()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) Encuentra y devuelve el siguiente token completo de este escáner.
> - [**nextLine()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) Avanza este escáner más allá de la línea actual y devuelve la entrada que se saltó.

Por lo tanto si usas nextLine() tomara el primer valor (`z`) y saltara hasta la obtención del tercer valor (`nombre2`).

---

Tu código solo necesita el cambio de método:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Introduce un número");
    int z = e.nextInt();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
    String nombre1 = e.nextLine();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
    String nombre2 = e.nextLine();

    System.out.println();


    System.out.println(z + ", " + nombre1 + ", " + nombre2);


}
```

Revisa este buen articulo:

[**¿CÚAL ES LA DIFERENCIA ENTRE NEXT() Y NEXTLINE() EN JAVA?**](https://respuestasit.wordpress.com/2015/06/13/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-next-y-nextline-en-java/)

Answer (score -1):

Un breve concepto acerca

next() solo lee hasta donde encuentra un espacio (hasta un espacio)

nextLine() lee todo incluyendo espacios (hasta un enter).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class EjercicioPractico {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

//Declaramos las variables con sus respectivos tipos de datos
String nombre1;
String nombre2;
int numero;


System.out.println("Introduce un numero");
numero = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Introduce un nombre");
nombre1 = sc.next();

System.out.println("Introduce otro nombre");
nombre2 = sc.next();


System.out.println(numero + " ," +nombre1+" ,"+nombre2);



}}
```

Answer (score -2):

Saludos, lo que veo de problema es que el objeto Scanner una vez que lo utilizas para datos enteros solo sirve para datos enteros, la solucion es declarar otro scar para datos de tipo String

```
 Scanner entero = new Scanner(System.in);
 Scanner cadena = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("Introduce un número");
int z = entero.nextInt();

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
String nombre1 = cadena.nextLine();

System.out.println();

System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
String nombre2 = cadena.nextLine();

System.out.println();


System.out.println(z + ", " + nombre1 + ", " + nombre2);
```

con eso deberia funcionar tu programa

Comment: Hola Samuel , en realidad se puede declarar solo una instancia de Scanner    para diferente tipo de datos.

Answer (score -2):

el problema no es el Scanner, el problema es el método que usas para leer un `String` , `nextLine()`, se va a la siguiente línea por eso ignora el primer input de nombre, intenta con `next()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Introduce un número");
    int z = e.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
    String nombre1 = e.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
    String nombre2 = e.next();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(z + ", " + nombre1 + ", " + nombre2);

}
```

**next ()**

> Devuelve el siguiente token si coincide con el patrón construido a
>   partir de la cadena especificada.

**nextLine ()**

> Avanza este escáner más allá de la línea actual y devuelve la entrada
>   que se saltó.