# ¿Cómo puedo llenar dinámicamente un vector mediante un ciclo for?

Tags: java, array

Estoy empezando a programar en Java ya que sé un poco de C++ y de desarrollo web; pero me quedé estancado en arreglos debido a que no puedo llenarlos a través del método `Scanner` de manera correcta; pues al colocar la cantidad de registros que quiero realizar, el programa me salta el primer registro, es decir, si digo que quiero registrar 2 nombres, al momento de ejecutar el ciclo for, se salta el primer registro, permitiéndome sólo registrar un nombre.

Aquí el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Registro {
   públic static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int filas;
      System.out.print("Cantidad de registros a realizar: ");
      filas = in.nextInt();
      String nombre [] = new String[filas];
      for(int i = 0; i < nombre. length; i++){  
       System.out.print("Registro " + i + ": ");
      nombre[i] = in.nextLine();
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Creo que esto ya lo contestarno varias veces es un tema del scanner y que lee en cada caso...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema clase Scanner en Java al introducir varios Strings como variables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121684/problema-clase-scanner-en-java-al-introducir-varios-strings-como-variables)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Scanner.nextLine() no actua correctamente despues de Scanner.nextInt()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que el primer `nextInt` no lee el salto de línea introducido cuando el usuario pulsa el `ENTER` tras introducir el número. Así que el primer `nextLine` te retornará inmediatamente el `ENTER` sin esperar a que metas nada.

La solución puede ser usar siempre `nextLine()` tanto para el entero como para las cadenas, y convertir el `String` en entero:

```
int filas= 0;
try {
    filas= Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```