# Java - Bug en while loop utilizando Scanner newLine

Tags: java, entrada

Estoy creando una aventura de texto, y tengo un while loop (game loop) en el cual se le pide una acción al usuario, de las cuales están: Explore, Move, Take, Inventory y Position. Y se recibe información del usuario usando la clase Scanner.

Para hacer más fácil pedir input, tengo esta clase:

```
public class Input {

    private static Input input = null;
    public Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    protected Input() {
        // o:
    }

    public static Input getInput() {
        if (input == null)
            input = new Input();
        return input;
    }

    public String getStringInput() {
        return scannerInput.nextLine();
    }

    public char getCharacterInput() {
        return scannerInput.next(".").charAt(0);
    }

}
```

Y este es el loop:

```
String action;
while (true) {
    System.out.println(currentRoom.getActionsString());
    action = input.getStringInput();

    if (action.split(" ").length > 1)
        player.processAction(action.split(" "));
    else
        player.processAction(action);
}
```

Método para procesar las acciones dentro de la clase Player:

```
public void processAction(String... actionDecision) {
    // Better-Better for sure!
    // Now make take and move much more
    // user friendly, so that you can
    // directly introduce the place you want to
    // move to or the name of the item you want to
    // take, and if not, it is alright too!

    switch(actionDecision[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "move":
            this.move();
            break;
        case "take":
            this.take();
            break;
        case "explore":
            this.explore();
            break;
        case "inventory":
            this.getFormattedInventory();
            break;
        case "position":
            this.getFormattedPosition();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry ):");
    }
}
```

El problema ocurre cuando el jugador elige "move" como su acción. El sistema de movimiento es por puntos cardinales, y de acuerdo a los cuartos adyacentes, puedo o no moverme a tales puntos. Pero cuando se elige la acción move, se procesa normalmente la acción, y el loop comienza de nuevo, pero automáticamente llama processAction y me arroja el valor por defecto, "Sorry ):" y luego vuelve a comenzar normalmente.

Ya noté que el problema viene de este método en la clase Input:

```
public String getStringInput() {
    return scannerInput.nextLine();
}
```

Si lo cambio a esto:

```
public String getStringInput() {
    return scannerInput.next();
}
```

No tengo ese bug, pero usando next en lugar nextLine no es conveniente para mi, porque next no parece leer más de una palabra, y estaré usando varargs bastante, por lo que necesito la string completa.

¿Por que está ocurriendo esto?

Comment: Supongo que el método `getCharacterInput()` lo utilizas en algún momento, ahi tienes el problema al mezclar `next()` y `nextLine()`

Comment: En el caso que como @Klaimmore indica estés usando el: `getCharacterInput()`, tal vez te interese usar algo así para coger directamente el `char` que buscas : `scannerInput.next(".").charAt(0);`

Comment: En esta pregunta mezclan `nextInt()` con `nextLine()` es similar a tu caso https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint

Comment: Pero el getCharacterInput es un método aparte que utilizo para tener la dirección en la que el jugador se quiere mover ('n', 'e', 's', 'w').
Así funciona el método para pedir input de caracteres rencinas.
Gracias por la pregunta Klainmore. ¿Crees que sea ese el problema entonces? ¿Mezclar los dos métodos?

Comment: Lo que dice @Klaimmore es que si usas el mismo objeto `Scanner` para `getCharacterInput()` y `getStringInput()` tienes que tener cuidado porque `next()` y `nextLine()`se comportan de forma diferente con respecto a los saltos de línea

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración David.
No estoy usando las dos, idealmente usaría nextLine(), porque next() parece que solo toma lo que venga antes el primer espacio en una string. Tal vez usando una regex pueda funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considera la siguiente entrada:

```
move
N
move
S
```

Lo que realmente hay en esa entrada, incluye saltos de linea:

```
move\n
N\n
move\n
S\n
```

Al leer la accion con `scannerInput.nextLine()` obtienes `move` sin el salto de linea, pero el scanner igual avanza la linea completa y se situa justo despues, quedando por procesar:

```
N\n
move\n
S\n
```

Al leer luego el parametro para la accion mover con `scannerInput.next(".").charAt(0)`, consumes solo un caracter de la entrada y obtienes `N`, pero lo que queda por consumir para el scanner es:

```
\n
move\n
S\n
```

Si luego, intentas leer otra accion, con `scannerInput.nextLine()`, obtendras una cadena vacia `""` y el scanner continuará avanzando, quedando:

```
move\n
S\n
```

Por eso es que hay que tener cuidado al mezclar `next()` y `nextLine()`. `next()` no consume los saltos de linea, `nextLine()` si.

Para tu caso, basta con consumir el resto de la linea en tu metodo:

```
public char getCharacterInput() {
    char c = scannerInput.next(".").charAt(0);
    scannerInput.nextLine(); //resto de la linea, avanzar a la siguiente
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa por no haber probado tu solución antes, no había tenido oportunidad.
Estoy impresionado con la solución, ahora funciona perfectamente.
Me gustaría entender mejor que estaba causando el problema.
Por lo pronto, ¿es la clase Scanner la mejor forma de pedir input en Java?
Muchas gracias por la solución.