# Duda Iteración En Java

Tags: java

En este ejercicio tengo un `switch` en el que la segunda opción sirve para realizar una acogida o adopción de uno de los animales de la hipotética protectora.

- **Case 2** se encuentra dentro de un `switch` en `Main`. (El `switch` está metido dentro de un `do`, y cuando selecciono **0** en el `switch`, se sale del `do{}` y el programa finaliza)
- **crearSolicitudAnimal** es un método que se encuentra dentro de `Main` (el primero de los 2 que aparecen)
- **protectora.crearSolicitudAnimal** es un método dentro de la clase `Protectora` que se encarga realmente de crear la solicitud como tal.

Mi problema creo que está en `protectora.crearSolicitudAnimal`, porque al ejecutar todo por primera vez me lo hace perfecto, llego hasta la parte de seleccionar `adopcion` o `solicitud` y vuelvo a ejecutar el `do{}`, haciendo que se muestre otra vez el menú inicial.

Pero cuando voy a seleccionar la `opción 2` otra vez, se salta la parte de escoger `animal` y me pregunta directamente si quiero `solicitud` o `adopción`.

Yo creo que mi problema está en ***String resultado*** pero no sé me ocurre nada para solventarlo.

```
case 2: /* Solicitar adopcion o acogida de animal */
    crearSolicitudAnimal(protectora);
    break;

private static void crearSolicitudAnimal(Protectora protectora) {
    System.out.println(protectora.crearSolicitudAnimal());
}

public String crearSolicitudAnimal() {
    System.out.print("Introduce el animal del que quieres hacer solicitud:\n");
    System.out.println("- Sombra\n- Copito\n- Scooby");
    String resultado = SOLICITUD.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nIntroduce el tipo de solicitud:\n");
    System.out.println("1. Acogida\n2. Adopcion");
    int opciontipo = SOLICITUD.nextInt();
    int j = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < numAnimales; i++) {
        if (animales[i].getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(resultado)) {
            j = i;
        }
    }
    if (j == -1) {
    } else {
        if (animales[j].esPosible()) {
            Solicitud[] solicitudes = new Solicitud[10];
            solicitudes[j] = new Solicitud(opciontipo);
            animales[j].setSolicitudes(solicitudes);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Java - Bug en while loop utilizando Scanner newLine](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148718/java-bug-en-while-loop-utilizando-scanner-newline)

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias