# Java problema con scanner.nextInt() ignora entrada

Tags: java, entrada

En el lenguaje de programación Java me surgió una duda al colocar por ejemplo un programa con dos *input* de esta manera

```
String probando_string = scanner.next();
int probando_int = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println(probando_string+probando_int);
```

Me debería pedir dos input pero solo enviando por ejemplo `PROBANDO 99` se "autoasigna"* la variable siguiente, ahora explicado el problema hago mi pregunta. ¿Por qué sucede eso? ¿El espacio es algún tipo de *split*?

INPUT DADO

> PROBANDO 99

Aca está mi pregunta, por tener en el programa dos scanner.next() debería pedirme DOS input pero solo envío una linea, de esa forma me autorellena la otra variable (probando_int) en este caso. Es mi pregunta porque sucede eso, ¿el espacio funciona como un *split*?

OUTPUT OBTENIDO

> PROBANDO99

Nota:
* Coloco entre comillas autoasigna porque pues no estoy muy seguro que esto suceda así.

Comment: Probando un poco más al intentar enviar una cadena con varios string, ósea separada por espacios ejemplo "Java es un super lenguaje 33" me lanzó un error que dice java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Scanner.nextLine() no actua correctamente despues de Scanner.nextInt()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint)

Comment: por favor agrega la salida actual y la salida esperada para poder ayudarte, a primera vista no se aprecia tu problema.

Comment: Es otra pregunta diferente a la antes mencionada.

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) en lugar de [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), de esta forma asignara a la variable `probando_string` el valor escrito hasta dar clic en la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
//String probando_string = scanner.next();
String probando_string = scanner.nextLine();
int probando_int = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println(probando_string+probando_int);
```

En realidad el espacio no funciona propiamente como split, lo que sucede es que al usar [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), Scanner toma la cadena introducida y la divide en elementos llamados tokens, el carácter predeterminado que sirve para determinar un separador de token es el espacio.

---

Usando [next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), Por ejemplo si introduces:

"`Java es un super lenguaje 33`"

Los token serian:

```
Java
es
un
super
lenguaje
33
```

De acuerdo a tu código `probando_string` tendría el valor `Java`, pero se provocaría un error del tipo `InputMismatchException`, ya que estaría tratando de asignar "es" como valor de `probando_int`.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner tiene varios funcionamientos un poco raretes.

Lo que te ocurre aquí básicamente es que al utilizar el método next() lo que está haciendo es coger palabra por palabra de tu input. Si hicieses nextLine() te recogería todo el String hasta el salto de línea (Enter).

Otro funcionamiento curioso es que cuando haces un nextInt() recoge dos inputs el Integer y la pulsación de Enter o salto de línea, y si pusieses una nextLine() detrás del nextInt() se te asignaría vacío.

Para solucionar este problema tras hacer un nextInt() hay que hacer un nextLine() vacío.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.

Un Saludo!