# ¿Por que no me funciona el metodo equals?Java POO

Tags: java, array, poo, bucle-for

estoy haciendo un programa llamado Sistema con menu incluido , todo funciona bien excepto en la parte donde tengo que verificar si el usuario y contraseña son los mismos ingresados de ser así devuelve un true , caso contrario false .Pero cuando accedo al método loguearse devuelve todo false , y a veces solo una vez devuelve true , pero lo demás todo false ,no se que puede ser por que yo ingreso bien el usuario y contraseña no si hay algun error al utilizar equals.

```
public class Usuario {
    private String contrasena;
    private String usuario;

    public Usuario(String usuario , String contrasena){
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
        this.usuario= usuario;
    }

    public void setContrasena(String contrasena){
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }

    public String getContrasena(){
        return this.contrasena;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario){
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getUsuario(){
        return this.usuario;
    }
}

public class Sistema {

    private String nombre;
    private Usuario lista[];
    int usuariosIngresados=0;

    public Sistema(String nombre , int cantidadDeUsuario){
        this.nombre = nombre ;
        this.lista = new Usuario[cantidadDeUsuario];
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre ;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public Usuario [] getLista (){
        return this.lista;
    }

    public void agregarUsuarios(Usuario usuario){
        lista[usuariosIngresados]= usuario;
        usuariosIngresados++;
    }

    public boolean loguearse(String nombreDeUsuario , String contrasena){
        boolean estado = false;

        for(int i = 0 ; i< lista.length ; i++ ){
            if((nombreDeUsuario.equals(lista[i].getUsuario()))&& (contrasena.equals(lista[i].getContrasena()))){
                estado= true ;
            } else {
                estado =  false;

            }

        }
        return estado;
    }    
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaSistema {
    public static void main (String [] args){

        /****************************************************************/

        //Variables de la clase Sistema 

        String nombre = " ";
        int cantidadDeUsuarios = 0;

        //Variable extra 

        int i = 0;
        int opciones = 0;

        //Variables de la clase Usuario

        String usuario =" ";
        String contrasena = " 

        /**********************************************************************/

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del sistema : ");
        nombre = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de usuarios : ");
        cantidadDeUsuarios = teclado.nextInt();
        Sistema sistema1 = new Sistema (nombre , cantidadDeUsuarios);


        //MENU DE OPCIONES

        while(opciones<=2){

            System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion : ");
            System.out.println("1.Agregar usuarios. ");
            System.out.println("2.Loguearse en el sistema.");
            opciones = teclado.nextInt();

            switch(opciones){

                case 1 :
                    for(i = 0 ; i < cantidadDeUsuarios ; i++){
                        System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese un nombre de usuario : ");
                        usuario=teclado.next();
                        System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese una contrasena : ");
                        contrasena = teclado.next();
                        sistema1.agregarUsuarios(new Usuario (usuario , contrasena));
                    }
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    for(i = 0 ; i < cantidadDeUsuarios ; i++){
                        System.out.println((i+1)+".Usuario : ");
                        usuario= teclado.next();
                        System.out.println((i+1)+".Contrasena : ");
                        contrasena = teclado.next();
                        System.out.println(sistema1.loguearse(usuario , contrasena));
                    }
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println("El menu solo tiene 2 opciones.Intente de nuevo.");
                    break;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Date cuenta que estas haciendo un for y modificando en cada iteración, solo te va a devolver `true`si el último usuario coincide, si no va a devolver `false` siempre.

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema viene por tu implementación en el for. Estas modificando la variable estado en todas las iteraciones por lo que su valor va a ser el de la última iteración. Si ese no es el usuario buscado te devolverá `false` aunque exista. Lo que tienes que hacer es acabar el for cuando encuentres al usuario. Si no lo encuentra hará el for entero

Te pongo solo tu método loguearse

```
public boolean loguearse(String nombreDeUsuario , String contrasena){

        boolean estado = false;
        for(int i = 0 ; i< lista.length && estado == false; i++ ){
            if((nombreDeUsuario.equals(lista[i].getUsuario()))&& (contrasena.equals(lista[i].getContrasena()))){
                estado= true ;
            }    
        }    
        return estado;
    }
```

Te explico lo que he hecho:
 - He puesto tambien como condicion de seguir en el for que estado == false. Esto es porque una vez encuentre el usuario no tiene sentido seguir buscando.
 - He eliminado la parte del else pues no es necesario. De hecho es lo que estaba haciendo que te funcionara mal

Comment: no es necesario preguntar en cada iteración por el estado ya que el estado cambiará una vez y esa vez queremos salir del loop así que basta con `estado = true; break;`. Es más, como no hace nada mas aparte del loop, en vez de `estado = true` puede hacer `return true`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, con el break me funciono :D , Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo muy básico de lo que te comentaba, espero te sirva:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    String nombre_a_validar = "Juan";
    boolean validado = false;
    al.add("Alberto");
    al.add("Juan");
    al.add("Jesus");
    al.add("Andres");

    //opcion 1
    for (String nombre : al) {
        if (nombre.equals(nombre_a_validar)) {
            validado = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    //opcion 2
    if(al.indexOf(nombre_a_validar) != -1) {
        validado = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede estar en cómo lees la opción del menú con nextInt. Mira esta otra pregunta a ver si encuentras respuesta:

[Scanner.nextLine() no actua correctamente despues de Scanner.nextInt()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas hacer es en el bucle de comprobación de la lista poner un break; cuando encuentres el usuario al que corresponden el nombre y contraseña, eso significara que has logueado, por lo tanto pones el estado a true, y rompes el bucle con break; no tiene sentido seguir el bucle si ya has logueado, así evitas que los posteriores usuarios de la lista te modifiquen el estado a false.

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Un ejemplo de implementación de lo que comentas sería ideal para considerarlo como una buena respuesta.