# Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.lang.Integer.getInteger(String)" is null

Tags: java

Hola no se por que me da error este pequeño código de preguntar por el número mayor.

Este es el código:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class HolaMundo {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println("Ingresa un numero");
            Scanner consola = new Scanner(System.in);
            int numero1 = Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Ingresa otro numero");
            int numero2 = Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine());
            
            if(numero1>numero2)
                System.out.println("El primero es el mayor");
            else
                System.out.println("El segundo es el mayor");
        }

}
```

Error marcado:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.lang.Integer.getInteger(String)" is null
> at HolaMundo.main(HolaMundo.java:9)
> C:\Users\Pino\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\Pino\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
> BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Una pregunta bien formularda, pero en futuras preguntas, estaría bien que mostraras cuál es la línea donde salta la excepción (en este caso la línea 9).

Answer (score 1):

```
int numero1 = Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine());
```

*Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine)* devuelve una instancia de *Integer*, un objeto. Luego la asignas a *numero1*, que es un *int*, una primitiva (no un objeto).

Primitivas y objetos son estructuras distintas; hasta Java 5 tendrías que haber hecho algo como

```
int numero1 = Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine()).intValue();
```

para que compilara.

Desde Java 5 el JVM puede hacer *autoboxing* y *unboxing*, que significa que si asignas un *Integer* a *int* (o viceversa)<sup>1</sup>, la propia JVM se encarga de interpretar el código que tú has puesto como lo que he escrito yo.

Pero aquí el problema es que *Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine())* está devolviendo *null*, y el JVM no puede hacer el *unboxing* ya que llamar a *intValue()* de *null* daría un NullPointerException.

El porqué al leer el entero te da *null* lo puedes encontrar en varias preguntas del sitio, como [ésta por ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint).

<sup>1</sup>Todas las primitivas (int, char, float...) tienen una clase "wrapper" equivalente (Integer, Character, Float...); el autoboxing y unboxing solo funciona entre una primitiva y su wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Sustituye `Integer.getInteger(consola.nextLine())` por `Integer.parseInt(consola.nextLine())`

```
int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(consola.nextLine());
int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(consola.nextLine());
```

Este metodo hace la conversion de String a int