# Problema con entrada de datos en java

Tags: java

Hola amigos estoy creando un programa en java pero a la hora de introducir estos datos por teclado el nextLine lo ignora y salta directo al nextInt, me pueden ayudar?.
Este es la parte de mi codigo:

```
         menu=entradadatos.nextInt();
         String descripcion;
         switch(menu)  {
      case 1:
        System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del gasto");
        descripcion= entradadatos.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el total del gasto");
        double gasto=entradadatos.nextDouble();
        nuevacuenta.addGasto(descripcion, gasto);
        System.out.println(nuevacuenta.getgastos());    
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del ingreso");
        descripcion=entradadatos.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el total del ingreso");
        double cantidad=entradadatos.nextInt();
        System.out.println(descripcion);
        System.out.println(cantidad);
        nuevacuenta.addIngresos(descripcion, cantidad);
        System.out.println(nuevacuenta.getingresos());
        break;
```

Comment: He encontrado esta referencia que explica tu problema
[problema con nextLine](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint) Básicamente el problema que te has encontrado es es que cuando introduces el primer entero lo introduces con un salto de línea. Tu primer nextInt no toma el salto de línea y entonces el nextline obtiene el salto de línea que le queda pendiente. Te recomienda hacer lo siguiente
``` java
int i2 = scan.nextInt();
String saltoDeLinea = scan.nextLine();
String s2 = scan.nextLine();
``` o leer siempre con nextLi

Comment: Al final lo he solucionado creando un scanner distinto para el string y otro para el int no creo que sea la solucion mas elegante pero asi funciona.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Scanner.nextLine() no actua correctamente despues de Scanner.nextInt()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22395/scanner-nextline-no-actua-correctamente-despues-de-scanner-nextint)

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es parsear el nextInt y el double

```
 menu=Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
     String descripcion;
     switch(menu)  {
  case 1:
    System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del gasto");
    descripcion= entradadatos.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el total del gasto");
    String gasto = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
    nuevacuenta.addGasto(descripcion, gasto);
    System.out.println(nuevacuenta.getgastos());    
    break;
case 2:
    System.out.println("Introduzca la descripcion del ingreso");
    descripcion=entradadatos.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el total del ingreso");
    String cantidad= double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine());
    System.out.println(descripcion);
    System.out.println(cantidad);
    nuevacuenta.addIngresos(descripcion, cantidad);
    System.out.println(nuevacuenta.getingresos());
    break;
```