# Tengo un problema con un programa de Java al convertir un String en entero

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto que me mandaron en clase, y me explicaron que un **String** daba menos problemas que un **entero** a la hora de hacer *condicionales* y *bucles*, y cuando quiero hacer un *condicional* o un *bucle* que implique el uso de números, hago un **cast** y convierto el **String** en **Entero** o cualquier otro valor numérico y nunca me había dado problemas hasta hoy. Ahora me crashea y no se por qué. Os paso el código, ¿alguien me podría indicar que ocurre? Muchas gracias.

```
import java.util.*;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        opcion1 p1 = new opcion1();
        opcion1 p2 = new opcion1();
        String linea;
        int opcion;
        do {
            System.out.println("Menú: " + "\n1- Crear Perfil." + "\n2- Cálculo del IMC." + "\n3- Seguir hábitos saludables."
                    + "\n4- Conocer si llevas una alimentación variada y rica para una buena salud." + "\n5- Salir del programa.");
            linea=sc.nextLine();
            opcion=Integer.parseInt(linea);
            if(opcion==1) {
                int numperfil;
                String eleccion;
                System.out.println("Has elegido crear un perfil");
                System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre:");
                p1.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu DNI:");
                do {
                    p1.setDNI(sc.nextLine());
                }while(p1.comprobarDNI(p1.getDNI())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu sexo: H/M");
                do {
                    p1.setSexo(sc.nextLine().charAt(0));
                }while(p1.ComprobarSexo(p1.getSexo())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu día de nacimiento:");
                do {
                    p1.setDnac(sc.nextInt());
                }while(p1.ComprobarDia(p1.getDnac())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu mes de nacimiento:");
                do {
                    p1.setMnac(sc.nextInt());
                }while(p1.ComprobarMes(p1.getMnac())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu año de nacimiento:");
                do {
                    p1.setAnac(sc.nextInt());
                }while(p1.ComprobarAño(p1.getAnac())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Perfil creado, tus datos son: " + p1.toString());
            }
        }while(opcion!=5);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error que devuelve?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, ordena tu problema... explicate bien...

Answer (score 1):

He llegado a leer las respuestas que habías publicado y creo que se te juntan dos problemas. Por cierto, para que la pregunta sea más completa, puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir lo que habías puesto como respuesta.

La excepción que te está dando es porque cuando se ejecuta por segunda vez la lectura de la opción escogida:

```
linea=sc.nextLine();
opcion=Integer.parseInt(linea);
```

el sc.nextLine() lee una línea vacía "", que en la siguiente línea se intenta convertir a un entero, por lo que parteInt suelta una excepción (lo hace siempre que se intenta convertir algo que no sea un número válido: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

La línea en blanco que lee el nextLine aparece porque los sc.nextInt que haces para leer enteros, justamente leen los enteros, pero se dejan los finales de línea/retorno de carro pendientes de leer. En https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22397/2619 lo explican mejor de lo que yo lo puedo hacer.

Hay varias opciones para arreglar esto. Una es hacer siempre un nextLine después de un nextInt para vaciar los retornos de carro pendientes (si solo tienes un valor por línea). Otra opción es usar siempre nextLine y después convertir al tipo que te haga falta.

Por supuesto, siempre tienes que controlar que lo se introduce por el teclado concuerda con lo que está esperando la aplicación y controlar los posibles errores.

Answer (score 0):

Para que te vuelva a salir el menú te recomiendo que uses el switch en vez de utilizar if. En tu caso el código quedaría asi:

```
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String linea;
    int opcion;
    boolean salir=false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Menú: " + "\n1- Crear Perfil." + "\n2- Cálculo del IMC." + "\n3- Seguir hábitos saludables."
                + "\n4- Conocer si llevas una alimentación variada y rica para una buena salud." + "\n5- Salir del programa.");
        linea=sc.nextLine();
        opcion=Integer.parseInt(linea);
        switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            int numperfil;
            String eleccion;
            System.out.println("Has elegido crear un perfil");
            System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre:");
            p1.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
            
            System.out.println("Introduce tu DNI:");
            do {
                p1.setDNI(sc.nextLine());
            }while(p1.comprobarDNI(p1.getDNI())!=true);
            
            System.out.println("Introduce tu sexo: H/M");
            do {
                p1.setSexo(sc.nextLine().charAt(0));
            }while(p1.ComprobarSexo(p1.getSexo())!=true);
            
            System.out.println("Introduce tu día de nacimiento:");
            do {
                p1.setDnac(sc.nextInt());
            }while(p1.ComprobarDia(p1.getDnac())!=true);
            
            System.out.println("Introduce tu mes de nacimiento:");
            do {
                p1.setMnac(sc.nextInt());
            }while(p1.ComprobarMes(p1.getMnac())!=true);
            
            System.out.println("Introduce tu año de nacimiento:");
            do {
                p1.setAnac(sc.nextInt());
            }while(p1.ComprobarAño(p1.getAnac())!=true);
            
            System.out.println("Perfil creado, tus datos son: " + p1.toString());
            
            break;
        case 5:
            salir=true;
        
        }
    }while(!salir);
    System.out.print("he salido");
}
```