# Problema al convertir un String en entero

Tags: java, poo, backend

Resulta que estoy haciendo un pequeño programa que en resumen, me muestra un menú principal con 5 opciones y mediante un bucle puedo navegar por las diferentes opciones, hasta que introduzco por teclado un 5 y el programa se termina. En clase nos acostumbró el profesor a usar un **String** y convertirlo a **entero** para poder trabajar con bucles y condicionales. El problema está en que cuando yo introduzco un 1 y termino de hacer lo que indica la opción 1, el programa me **crashea** con una excepción; cuando el programa me debe retornar al menú principal y darme la opción de volver a elegir las diferentes opciones. Y el error me indica que está en la línea donde  hice el cast y no entiendo por qué, ya que si lo hago los condicionales con un número entero el programa me salta líneas y es un poco caótico. Os comparto el código de lo que llevo y también una captura del mensaje de excepción que me marca. Muchas gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        opcion1 p1 = new opcion1();
        opcion1 p2 = new opcion1();
        String linea;
        int opcion;
        do {
            System.out.println("Menú: " + "\n1- Crear Perfil." + "\n2- Cálculo del IMC." + "\n3- Seguir hábitos saludables."
                    + "\n4- Conocer si llevas una alimentación variada y rica para una buena salud." + "\n5- Salir del programa.");
            linea=sc.nextLine();
            opcion=Integer.parseInt(linea);
            if(opcion==1) {
                int numperfil;
                String eleccion;
                System.out.println("Has elegido crear un perfil");
                System.out.println("Introduce tu nombre:");
                p1.setNombre(sc.nextLine());
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu DNI:");
                do {
                    p1.setDNI(sc.nextLine());
                }while(p1.comprobarDNI(p1.getDNI())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu sexo: H/M");
                do {
                    p1.setSexo(sc.nextLine().charAt(0));
                }while(p1.ComprobarSexo(p1.getSexo())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu día de nacimiento:");
                do {
                    p1.setDnac(sc.nextInt());
                }while(p1.ComprobarDia(p1.getDnac())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu mes de nacimiento:");
                do {
                    p1.setMnac(sc.nextInt());
                }while(p1.ComprobarMes(p1.getMnac())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Introduce tu año de nacimiento:");
                do {
                    p1.setAnac(sc.nextInt());
                }while(p1.ComprobarAño(p1.getAnac())!=true);
                
                System.out.println("Perfil creado, tus datos son: " + p1.toString());
            }   
        }while(opcion!=5);
    }
```

[image: Y este es el mensaje de excepción que me sale.]

Comment: usa sc.next() en vez de nextLine()

Comment: @BetaM si esa pregunta también la hizo el xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copio la respuesta a tu pregunta anterior.

Creo que se te juntan dos problemas.

La excepción que te está dando es porque cuando se ejecuta por segunda vez la lectura de la opción escogida:

```
linea=sc.nextLine();
opcion=Integer.parseInt(linea);
```

el sc.nextLine() lee una línea vacía "", que en la siguiente línea se intenta convertir a un entero, por lo que parteInt suelta una excepción (lo hace siempre que se intenta convertir algo que no sea un número válido: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

La línea en blanco que lee el nextLine aparece porque los sc.nextInt que haces para leer enteros, justamente leen los enteros, pero se dejan los finales de línea/retorno de carro pendientes de leer. En https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22397/2619 lo explican mejor de lo que yo lo puedo hacer.

Hay varias opciones para arreglar esto. Una es hacer siempre un nextLine después de un nextInt para vaciar los retornos de carro pendientes (si solo tienes un valor por línea). Otra opción es usar siempre nextLine y después convertir al tipo que te haga falta.

Por supuesto, siempre tienes que controlar que lo se introduce por el teclado concuerda con lo que está esperando la aplicación y controlar los posibles errores.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya conseguí solucionarlo. Con un sc.nextLine() vacío ya me retorno bien al menú. Lo tendré en cuenta para las proximas veces que me ocurra.

Comment: Es la misma pregunta que hizo antes. Podrías simplemente enviarle un comentario con el enlace a tu otra respuesta.