# el ciclo no se repite correctamente

Tags: java, while

necesito una pequeña ayuda

Quiero ingresar n cantidad de alumnos con sus respectivas notas hasta que finalice el programa al escribir la palabra "salir", el problema es que, en el 1er recorrido, el ciclo funciona perfecto, primero me pide el nombre del alumno, luego su nota y lo muestra en consola... para los posteriores recorridos, me pide el nombre del alumno en la opcion de la nota, por tanto me produce el error. No consigo hacer que me pida el nombre y las notas por separado n cantidad de veces hasta que se escriba la palabra "salir"

```
Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    
String registro="";
boolean continuar;
double calificacion;
    
//Registro de alumnos
do {
        continuar=false;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del alumno (o SALIR para terminar): ");
        registro = entrada.nextLine();
    
        if(registro.equals("salir")||registro.equals("Salir")||registro.equals("SALIR")) {
            continuar=false;
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            continuar=true;
            System.out.println("Alumno: "+registro);
            
                System.out.println("ingrese la nota del alumno");
                calificacion=entrada.nextDouble();
            }           
    }while(continuar);
```

Comment: Debuguea para que detectes dd está el error

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que cuando introduces valores numéricos, se queda atrás un salto de línea, porque los métodos como `nextDouble()` o `nextInt()` no consumen ese salto de línea, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22397/29967) para más detalles.

Dicho eso, tu código va a estallar si el usuario introduce un valor no válido cuando esperas el double y eso debes controlarlo.

Así debería funcionar (me he permitido organizar mejor / simplificar algunas cosas que he puesto en comentarios):

```
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    //Inicializar registro es redundante
    String registro;
    boolean continuar;
    double calificacion;
    //Registro de alumnos
    do {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del alumno (o SALIR para terminar): ");
        registro = entrada.next();
        //Usamos equalsIgnoreCase, que sirve para "salir", "SALIR", "salIR" ...
        continuar=!registro.equalsIgnoreCase("salir");
        if(continuar) {
            System.out.println("Alumno: " + registro);
            System.out.print("ingrese la nota del alumno: ");
            //No saldrá de este bloque, hasta que no escriba un valor numérico
            while (!entrada.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Dato inválido, por favor ingrese un valor numérico");
                entrada.next();
            }
            calificacion = entrada.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Nota: " + calificacion);
        }
    }while(continuar);
    //Colocamos la salida fuera del bloque
    //Convendría cerrar el Scanner si no seguirás usándolo
    entrada.close();
    System.exit(0);
```

#### Prueba

```
Ingrese el nombre del alumno (o SALIR para terminar): 
Juan
Alumno: Juan
ingrese la nota del alumno: 10
Nota: 10.0
Ingrese el nombre del alumno (o SALIR para terminar): 
Marta
Alumno: Marta
ingrese la nota del alumno: 8
Nota: 8.0
Ingrese el nombre del alumno (o SALIR para terminar): 
Miguel
Alumno: Miguel
ingrese la nota del alumno: 7
Nota: 7.0
Ingrese el nombre del alumno (o SALIR para terminar): 
SALir
```